# Kendo UI Angular 2+ TextBox Floating Labels overlapping

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm testing floatingLabel ([docs](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/textbox/#toc-implementing-floating-labels)) but using ngModel, label overlaps the content

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <kendo-textbox-container floatingLabel="First name">
        <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="value"/>
      </kendo-textbox-container>
    `
   })
export export class AppComponent {
  value:string = 'hello'
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Here the Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/SUBw7zrUT2gsx4JZeGKD?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suitable workaround. It manually sets the `focused` flag of the container, so that the label goes to the other position.

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <kendo-textbox-container floatingLabel="First name">
        <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="value"/>
      </kendo-textbox-container>
    `
   })
export export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  value:string = 'hello'

  @ViewChild(TextBoxContainerComponent) container;

  // workaround for floatingLabel overlapping
  ngAfterViewInit() {
      window.setTimeout(() => this.container.focused = true, 0);
  }
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Problem is you give value to the ngModel Variable. thats the problem

update like this.

```
value:string = 'hello'
      to
value:string = '';  or value:string;
```

declare Empty Variable.

use place holder ---> `floatingLabel="First name"`  like this

its solved your problem!.

Iam updated your plunker code iam checked its working. check this code and run.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <kendo-textbox-container floatingLabel="First name">
        <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="value"/>
      </kendo-textbox-container>
    `
   })
export export class AppComponent {
  value:string = '';
}
```

Comment: I don't understand "use place holder ---> floatingLabel="First name" like this". I don't want use placeholder

Comment: label overlaps the content >>>>>your Problem this. 
so thats why iam tell dont use two type of assigning values..
use
            floatingLabel="First name" (or)   value:string = 'hello'

Comment: I need to assign value AND see floatingLabel as the second image in the screenshot. The problem is that, when "blur",the floatingLabel return on the content instead of block over the input

Comment: This text box not suitable for you.  i think you said "i need to assign" so plz remove "floatingLabel" and use it......

Thanks for your unusable Answer Award.